# einops not equivalent to torch.chunk?

Tags: torch, einops

I'm trying to replicate the following 2 lines in einops:

```py
emb = emb[..., None, None]
cond_w, cond_b = th.chunk(emb, 2, dim=1)
```

So far, I've managed to get:

```
emb = rearrange(emb, "b (c h w) -> b c h w", w=1, h=1)
cond_w, cond_b = th.chunk(emb, 2, dim=1)
```

This works fine.
But, when I do:

```
emb = rearrange(emb, "b (c h w) -> b c h w", w=1, h=1)
cond_w, cond_b = rearrange(emb, "b (split c) ... -> b split c ...", split=2)
```

The output is not the same. (Even though the shapes are).
Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
    cond_w, cond_b = rearrange(b_t, "b (split c) ... -> split b c ...", split=2)
```

Comment: you could complete both rearranges in a single step:

cond_w, cond_b = rearrange(emb, "b (split c) -> b split c 1 1", split=2)